# Hiding UITextView and UILabels in Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitextfield, uilabel

I have a picker view and when a user picks a certain value from picker view I want to hide certain textviews and labels together:

[label1] [----textview1----]

[label2] [----textview2----]

[label3] [----textview3----]

so what I want is:

```
if (picker value is equal to "someValue")
{
 - hide label 2 and textview 2
 - shift label 3 and text view 3 to be positioned below label 1 and textview1
}
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28305243/1013536) where I change priorities and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026577/1013536) also  but still no luck. 
I need to hide the label and textview together at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set constraints like this

[image]

Then what it looks like in gif

[image]

Code
Keep 3 property

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *secondLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *secondTextfield;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *toChangeConstraint;
```

Then hide

```
  self.secondLabel.hidden = true;
self.secondTextfield.hidden = true;
self.toChangeConstraint.constant = -20;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Then outlet constraint is this one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your views are laid out. I would suggest 2 approaches:

1) Wrap each pair of textView + label in a wrapperView. Make an IBOutlet to a height constraint of every wrapper viewView. Then you can hide rows like this:

```
wrapperView2HeightConstraint.constant = 0;
[wrapperView2 layoutIfNeeded];
```

You might need to set `wrapperView1.clipsSubviews = YES;` so subviews are actually hidden.

2) The other approach is just to use `UITableView` and put each pair in a `UITableViewCell`. Then you can easily manipulate which cells are hidden on `[tableView reloadData];`. There's even a built in animation for that.

Answer (score 0):

How about you set tag of textField and Label as textfield's tag tobe started out with 1,2,and soon and Label tag to be set as 51,52 and so on . so that they've a diff of 50 b/w them. and you can set them label.hidden and textview.hidden